# A question about the derivation of Poisson formula with respect to 2-dimensional wave equation

Tags: integration, wave-equation

In section 2.4 (wave equation) of *Partial Differential Equation (Evans)*, the author used the descent method to derive the Poisson's formula for two-dimensional wave equation.

For the $n=3$ case, the author has derived the Kirchhoff's formula for the IVP problem of the wave equation:
$$\begin{cases}
u_{tt}-\Delta u=0 & \text{in}\;\mathbb{R}^n\times (0,+\infty) \\
u=g,\; u_t=h & \text{on}\;\mathbb{R}^n\times\{t=0\}
\end{cases}$$
i.e.,
$$u(x,t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\biggl(\frac{1}{4\pi t}\int_{\partial B(x,t)}g\,\mathrm{d}S\bigg)+\frac{1}{4\pi t}\int_{\partial B(x,t)}h\,\mathrm{d}S.$$

For the $n=2$ case, assume $u\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^2\times [0,+\infty))$ solves the above IVP and write
$$\bar{u}(x_1,x_2,x_3,t):=u(x_1,x_2,t),$$
$$\bar{g}(x_1,x_2,x_3):=g(x_1,x_2),\quad \bar{h}(x_1,x_2,x_3):=h(x_1,x_2),$$
$$x=(x_1,x_2),\quad \bar{x}=(x_1,x_2,x_3).$$
Then $\bar{u}$ solves
$$\begin{cases}
\bar{u}_{tt}-\Delta \bar{u}=0 & \text{in}\;\mathbb{R}^3\times (0,+\infty), \\
\bar{u}=\bar{g},\; \bar{u}_t=\bar{h} & \text{on}\;\mathbb{R}^3\times\{t=0\},
\end{cases}$$
and hence
$$u(x,t)=\bar{u}(\bar{x},t)=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\biggl(\frac{1}{4\pi t}\int_{\partial \bar{B}(\bar{x},t)}\bar{g}\,\mathrm{d}\bar{S}\bigg)+\frac{1}{4\pi t}\int_{\partial \bar{B}(\bar{x},t)}\bar{h}\,\mathrm{d}\bar{S},$$
where $\bar{B}(\bar{x},t)$ denotes the ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with center $\bar{x}$ and radius $t>0$ and $\mathrm{d}\bar{S}$ denotes the two-dimensional surface measure on $\partial\bar{B}(\bar{x},t)$.

My question is the text in the following:
**How can we deduce that**
$$\int_{\partial\bar{B}(\bar{x},t)}\bar{g}\,\mathrm{d}\bar{S}=2\int_{B(x,t)}g(y)\sqrt{1+|D\gamma(y)|^2}\,\mathrm{d}y?$$
in which $\gamma(y)=\sqrt{t^2-|y-x|^2}$. I think it may be more helpful to explain by using some figures.